# List files in directory without Android READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I'm using the package `flutter_file_picker` to allow the user to select a directory. Then, listing out the media files in that directory.

```
String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
if (selectedDirectory != null) {
  final files = Directory(selectedDirectory).list().toList();
  log(files.toString());
}
```

Using the permission (android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) and requesting it with the permission_manager plugin's `await Permission.photos.request();` method, **it works great**.

This year, apps with "one-time" or "infrequent" use of the permission will need to migrate away from using android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES to comply with Google Play policies.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14115180#zippy=

> Mid 2024: Apps with one-time or infrequent use of photos requested to use a system photo picker and remove READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions from their app manifest.

When I try to remove the `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission from the Android manifest, only folders and files that *the app created* are listed. Other files aren't listed. It will list sub-folders like `'/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/.thumbnails'` but not the media files in the directory. This is testing with Android 13 and 14.

Is there a way to list files in the directory returned by `FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath` without the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission?

Comment: No, no, no, no.. Keep that permission until doomsday. And-or let your app list that folder every day then you can keep it.

Comment: Cannot you use SAF to pick a directory? Then you can list all files in it without any permission.

Comment: You're probably right about waiting. Maybe by then there will be a solution/clearer migration path. Unfortunately, for my app there isn't really one folder that I can list (in that sense). Users select a folder to import a large image sequence. It's definitely a "one-time" use of the permission, so I doubt Google Play would let it slide.

Comment: My hope was that there was a Dart/Flutter solution, otherwise SAF is probably the solution.